# opensearch in wikipedia result as jsonobject in java

Tags: java, json, wikipedia-api

I want to use opensearch in wikipedia (cause the results is what I look for) and parse the result of this query using java :

https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=soleil&format=json

But the result does not look as json format :

```
    [
  "soleil",
  [
    "Soleil",
    "Soleil vert",
    "Soleilhas",
    "Soleil Royal (1749)",
    "Soleil Moon Frye",
    "Soleil levant (film)",
    "Soleil Royal (1669)",
    "Soleil trompeur",
    "Soleil Productions",
    "Soleils (association)"
  ],
  [
    "Le Soleil est l’étoile du Système solaire. Dans la classification astronomique, c’est une étoile de type naine jaune d'une masse d'environ 1,9891 ×\u202f1030 kg, composée d’hydrogène (75 % de la masse ou 92 % du volume) et d’hélium (25 % de la masse ou 8 % du volume).",
    "Soleil vert (Soylent Green) est un film américain d'anticipation réalisé par Richard Fleischer, sorti en 1973 et inspiré du roman Make room!",
    "Soleilhas est une commune française, située dans le département des Alpes-de-Haute-Provence en région Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur.",
    "Le Soleil-Royal est un navire de guerre français en service de 1750 à 1759. C'est un vaisseau de ligne de deuxième rang à deux ponts portant 80 canons, le troisième du nom dans la marine française.",
    "Soleil Moon Frye est une actrice américaine, née le 6 août 1976, à Glendora, Californie.",
    "Soleil levant (Rising Sun) est un thriller américain réalisé par Philip Kaufman, sorti en 1993. Le film met en vedette Sean Connery (également producteur délégué du film), Wesley Snipes, Harvey Keitel et Cary-Hiroyuki Tagawa.",
    "Le Soleil-Royal est un navire de guerre français, en service de 1669 à 1692. C'est un vaisseau de ligne de premier rang, portant 98 puis 104 canons sur trois ponts.",
    "Soleil trompeur (en russe : Утомлённые солнцем, Outomlionnyïé solntsem) est un film du réalisateur et acteur russe Nikita Mikhalkov, sorti en salles en 1994. Ce film a été récompensé par l'Oscar du meilleur film en langue étrangère et par le Grand Prix du jury au festival de Cannes.",
    "Soleil Productions est un éditeur français de bande dessinée localisé à Toulon.",
    "Soleils est une association à but humanitaire implantée sur le campus rennais de Supélec (École Supérieure d'Electricité)."
  ],
  [
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_vert",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleilhas",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_Royal_(1749)",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_Moon_Frye",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_levant_(film)",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_Royal_(1669)",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_trompeur",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_Productions",
    "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleils_(association)"
  ]
]
```

And I don't know how to use it as a list in my java code (using commons-io-2.6.jar and java-json.jar) :

String url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=soleil&format=json";

```
    String jsonText = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);

    json.getJSONArray(key); // no key in the json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikipedia response certainly is a valid JSON, although the structure is a bit unfortunate.
They do it this way to save transfers ( as they don't have to include the keys in the response JSON ).

Now back to that array structure:

- First element is the query string.
- Second element is an array containing titles of found pages.
- Third element is an array containing descriptions of found pages.
- Fourth element is an array containing URLs of found pages.

Example code for reading this response ( using Jackson, industry standard JSON library ):

```
public void printWikipediaResults() throws IOException {
    JsonNode tree = new ObjectMapper().readTree("<Wikipedia JSON>");

    // get number of results ( length of titles array )
    int totalResults = tree.get(1).size();
    // initialize a new ArrayList to store the WikiArticles into
    List<WikiArticle> results = new ArrayList<>(totalResults);
    // for each article, create a new object from the data contained in the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < totalResults; i++) {
        results.add(new WikiArticle(
                tree.get(1).get(i).asText(),
                tree.get(2).get(i).asText(),
                tree.get(3).get(i).asText()
        ));
    }

    System.out.println("Showing results for: " + tree.get(0).asText());
    for (WikiArticle article : results) {
        System.out.println(article.title + ": " + article.url);
    }
}

public static class WikiArticle {
    public String title;
    public String desc;
    public String url;

    public WikiArticle(String title, String desc, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Showing results for: soleil
Soleil: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil
Soleil vert: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_vert
Soleilhas: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleilhas
Soleil Royal (1749): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_Royal_(1749)
Soleil Moon Frye: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_Moon_Frye
Soleil levant (film): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_levant_(film)
Soleil Royal (1669): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_Royal_(1669)
Soleil trompeur: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_trompeur
Soleil Productions: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleil_Productions
Soleils (association): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soleils_(association)
```

Comment: It's not unfortunate, it's an implementation of the [OpenSearch API](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch/blob/master/opensearch-1-1-draft-6.md#opensearch-response-elements). Unless you are writing a web browser, there's no reason for you to use it (as the documentation [points out](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch)). You should probably use the [prefixsearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Prefixsearch) API instead.