# How do i map this json response correclty?

Tags: java, json, gson

Im having trouble mapping this wikipedia opensearch json response to my model. Im using gson to map the response

```
[
    "Computer",
    [
        "Computer",
        "Computer program",
        "Computer science",
        "Computer network",
        "Computer keyboard",
        "Computer mouse",
        "Computer security",
        "Computer virus",
        "Computer data storage",
        "Computer hardware"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_program",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_keyboard",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_mouse",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_data_storage",
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_hardware"
    ]
]
```

The URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=Computer&format=json

My model:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class OpensearchResponse {

    String searchTerm;

    String[] possibilities;

    String[] empty;

    String[] references;
    
}
```

When i try to map the json respone like so:

```
var opensearchResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, OpensearchResponse.class);
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I suspect my data structure is very wrong. But what exactly?

Comment: A JSON valid string is , at top-level an object with keys and values, you'r is an object

Comment: As pointed out by @azro , it isn't a valid JSON string to parse it using gson or any other json parser. What you have here is an object of values without any keys.

You'll have to parse the String into your object structure. This question has same requirements as - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161807/opensearch-in-wikipedia-result-as-jsonobject-in-java

Comment: Your JSON is in Array format and not Object format. Object format can be mapped to respective Java Class (object) while Array format can be mapped to Java List (or Collection). You should be expecting List while mapping instead of `OpensearchResponse`. Additionally, all elements of JSON outer array are not in similar format (String v/s Array/List). If all elements were of same format, it can be mapped to `List<String>` or `List<List<String>>` etc. In your case, it can only be `List<Object>`. Alternative is to use JSON in Object format by adding missing keys (key-value format).

Comment: Thank you! I just realized :)